# iOS project build failed when importing "ADAL/ADAuthenticationContext.h"

Tags: objective-c, react-native, adal

I have a react-native project and I am trying to add Adal-iOS to that. I am trying to use the official plugin from Microsoft.

I am finally able to build the project after importing the library via CocoPods. However, now, when I am trying to use the build fails when I import "ADAL/ADAuthenticationContext.h". Error message is : /ADAL/ADAuthenticationContext.h:127:12: Unknown type name 'WebViewType'.

Looking more into that file, I see the following:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    __weak WebViewType* _webView;
#else 
    WebViewType* _webView;
#endif
}
```

looking deeper into WebViewType, I found:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
//iOS:
typedef UIWebView WebViewType;
#else
//OS X:
#   include <WebKit/WebKit.h>
typedef WebView   WebViewType;
#endif
```

I am not sure what exactly is happening and any help is welcome !

Comment: what version of ADAL are you importing? what is your podfile script?

Comment: did you found the solution? please help me out I'm facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `#import ADAL/ADAL.h` where you are defining `completionBlock`.